# Is this physics model accurate?

Tags: acceleration, textbook-erratum

I have been playing an online game in which players command space ships, and the creators claim an accurate physics model is in place. The thrust force my craft can exert is 550N (supposedly) and the mass is 20500 kg. The game limits velocity to roughly 200m/s depending on craft type. Doing the math for acceleration I find a value of approximately .0207 m/s^2, which seems incorrect, considering the craft takes about ten seconds to reach full speed, but I'm just learning to apply these equations now so I may be wrong. 
First off, how close is this physics model to reality, of course excluding the fictional max speed?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  Their model is very far from physics.  However, this may be explained by a simple units error

We could actually calculate how much thrust you would need to accelerate from 0 to 200m/s in 10 seconds.  That's an acceleration of 20m/s^2.  Simply using F=ma, we can see that this calls for a force of 410,000N, not 550N!

However, if I phrase that in terms of kilonewtons, that's 410kN.  410 is close enough to 550 to make me think that what really happened was nothing more than a units error -- they wrote `N` when they intended to write `kN`

550kN of force would give you an acceleration of 20.7m/s^2, meaning you would reach 200m/s in 9.66 seconds... which is right about what you observed.